# Sending the same OTP as long as it didn't expire

Tags: security, cryptography

I have a system that sends a 6-digit OTP by SMS and Email.

I was thinking to make it send the same OTP (per user) as long as it didn't expire (in my case it's 10 minutes).

So if for example a user created an OTP now, and he comes back in 5 minutes, he will receive the same OTP (as long as the time hasn't passed or that the OTP was not used)

Does it have any security risks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the same value is transmitted twice, and if the first transmision was copied/eavesdropped/etc, the attackers window of oportunity is bigger. If transmission 2 would invalidate transmission 1, the information of transmission 1 would become useless at that point and the attacker would be required to obtain transmission 2 to keep the login factor (until it expires/is used). if the same value is used, the attackers window of oportunity in this case would remain open until the 10 minutes expire or the value is actually used and capturing transmission 2 would not be necessaray.

Depending on the required level of security that might or might not be a factor for you. But that already takes attackers into consideration that are able to steal a value at least once, so... maybe not your typical attacker. In other words: Definitely consider this for some ICBM launch codes, but for your every day, dollar-store, end-customer shop system, attackers with this kind of capabilities might be a little far fetched, and even if such an attacker is likely in your situation and is to be defended against, the bigger window of oportunity is probably not the biggest of your concerns... Multi factor auth probably raises the bar way more.

Comment: thanks, after reading your comment I ended up just creating a new OTP every time